# .htaccess remap redirect on different subdomain

Tags: php, angularjs, facebook, .htaccess

I am trying to make my AngularJS application discoverable by social networks, and I've came across the following github page:

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angular-social-demo

However I got stuck at .htaccess step. The following code is being used to redirect (using remapping) the facebook/twitter/google bots to different url (on same domain):

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

# allow social media crawlers to work by redirecting them to a server-rendered static version on the page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule album/(\d*)$ http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/experiments/angular-social-demo/server/static-page.php?id=$1 [P]

</ifModule>
```

What I am trying to do, is very similar to what he did, however my API is a subdomain.

Is .htaccess redirect remapping possible when a different subdomain is used?

Example:

http://www.example.com/test/123 remap to: http://api.example.com/title/test/123 and keep browser url as: http://www.example.com/test/123

Comment: Both of subdomains are stored on same physical server.

Comment: Since this uses the `P` flag to proxy the requests, I don’t see why that shouldn’t work.